# Check developer console in MS teams Tab App

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a personal Tabs app and deployed the same on MS teams.
Things are working as expected, but at 1 stage of time, my application goes back to the original "contentUrl" page as defined in the manifest.json file.
This might be an issue with my frontend code, so i wanted to understand how can we debug the frontend developer console to check if there's any error being thrown from my application?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to figure out what is going on is to use the DevTools. To use DevTools in the desktop client, you must:

Ensure you have enabled developer preview.

1. Open up a tab so you have something to inspect with the DevTools.
2. Open the DevTools one of the following ways:
3. On Windows, you open DevTools via the Microsoft Teams icon in the
   desktop tray.

The following example shows DevTools open and inspecting a tab configuration dialog:
[image]

Ref Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Comment: please confirm your issue is resolved or still looking for the help?